# how to pass parameters when i navigate back using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angularjs is re-using the previous view's controller when i navigate backwards.

```
$window.history.back();
```

i want to call a refresh when the previous view is reloaded (in some cases).  how do i pass parameters to the previous controller as i go "back" to it?  or is there a better way to navigate backward with angularjs?

passing parameters forwards is easily done via query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between controllers can easily be done by creating a custom service and then injecting that service into whatever controllers you wish.

Here's a quick and dirty example getting/setting a controller's state-data in a service with the goal of persisting the data between multiple instantiations of the controller.

Controller:

```
var list;

list = angular.module('app.list', ['services.controller_state']);

list.controller('ListCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'ControllerState', function($scope, ControllerState) {
    var savedParams;
    savedParams = ControllerState.getParams();
    savedParams.data1 = "changed";
    return ControllerState.setParams(savedParams);
  }
]);
```

Service:

```
var module;

module = angular.module("services.controller_state", []);

module.factory("ControllerState", function() {
  var params;
  params = {
    data1: "foo",
    data2: "bar",
    data3: "zig",
    data4: "zag"
  };
  return {
    getParams: function() {
      return params;
    },
    setParams: function(prms) {
      var item, _results;
      _results = [];
      for (item in prms) {
        _results.push(params[item] = prms[item]);
      }
      return _results;
    }
  };
});
```

If the JavaScript looks funky, it's because I mostly write CoffeeScript and used a converter.

Comment: thanks that is an ok option.  i am still thinking i may be missing a simpler answer more specifically related to the subject of navigating backwards

Comment: Considering that the controller/scope pair is destroyed when you navigate away (bye bye data), and that the back feature uses the URL stored in the history (no new query parameters), it may be your only option is to use a service. 

Unless there is some magic you can do by editing the URL history and modifying the stored query params. I don't know of any way to do this tho.

Comment: ok, that is interesting.  in my case the controller is NOT being destroyed when i navigate away, but i am using ngView and loading partials.  when i navigate back, the previous controller instance is being re-used.  is there a way to FORCE it to instantiate a new controller?